# Find position of parent node in XML tree using VBA

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I am using VBA in Excel. I have a XML file that has this structure:

```
<Level_A>
    <Level_B>
        <Level_C>First value</Level_C>
        <Level_C>Second value</Level_C>
    </Level_B>
    <Level_B>
        <Level_C>Third value</Level_C>
        <Level_C>Fourth value</Level_C>
    </Level_B>
</Level_A>
```

I want to

- loop through all `Level_C` nodes and to
- store the (unique) **position** of each parent node within in the XML structure in an *array*.

There are two `Level_B` (parent) nodes in the above sample, so the first node would return position 0 and the second node position 1.

I would like these results:

- First value, Parent node position in XML tree is 0.
- Second value, Parent node position in XML tree is 0.
- Third value, Parent node position in XML tree is 1.
- Fourth value, Parent node position in XML tree is 1.

The `Level_B` (parent) nodes don't have any text or attributes.

**Question**

How can I find their (unique) position number in the XML tree?

A `Level_B` node can contain 0, 1 or 2 Level_C nodes. I need to get all Level_C nodes in the XML file and know the (unique) position number of their parent node.

I can read the basename of the parent node Level_B by using this code:

```
NodePath(i).ParentNode.BaseName
```

I'm looking for the same functionality but this time reading the unique position of the Level_B node.

**Why am I asking this?**

I have to read a lot of different XML files with financial data. All files contain the same type of information, but are structured in different ways. What all XML files have in common is that they have a financial value like $ 100.00.

I want to have flexible code so that I can just point to the nodepath of the financial value and then simply go up or down in the XML tree to find all the other data I need.

Below is an example of two of the XML structures I need to read (there are even more). I want to loop through the nodes containing the financial values and have the flexibility go up or down the XML tree to find the currency, transaction ID and a lot of other data. Sometimes I need to go up even 5 parent nodes to find what I need.

In this example there is no tag or attribute with a unique transaction ID:

```
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <financialvalues>
            <value>100.00</value>
            <value>200.00</value>
        </financialvalues>
    </transaction>
    <transaction>
        <currency>USD</currency>
        <financialvalues>
            <value>300.00</value>
            <value>400.00</value>
        </financialvalues>
    </transaction>
</transactions>
```

In this other XML structure there is a unique transaction ID in the tag TransactionID. (Which makes it easier...)

```
<transactions>
    <transaction>
        <transactionID>5</transactionID>
        <lines>
            <line>
                <financialvalue>100.00</value>
                <currency>USD</currency>
            </line>
            <line>
                <financialvalue>200.00</value>
                <currency>USD</currency>
            </line>
         </lines>
    </transaction>
</transactions>
```

I don't want to write a seperate script for each XML structure, but have the flexibility to just loop through the FinancialValue tags of each XML file and then go up or down to find what I need.

So in the first XML structure there is no tag or attribute telling me the unique TransactionID. Therefore I would like to access the position number of the parent Transaction so that I know which FinancialValue belongs to which transaction.

Comment: Why don't you loop through B nodes? Looks grouped to me

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to avoid looping through <Level_B>. I want to retrieve the data from <Level_B> while looping through <Level_C>. I am able to do this when <Level_C> uses an ID-attribute, but in this case there are no ID-attributes. I know each node has an unique position in the XML tree, so my idea is to retrieve the unique position. But I don't know how.

Comment: Does each `Level_B` node contain one or more `Level_C` nodes?

Comment: A Level_B node can contain 0, 1 or 2 Level_C nodes. I need to get all Level_C nodes in the XML file and know the unique position number of their parent node.

Comment: Vote to reopen as it's clear that @Zxcv wants to get identifying parent node positions (formulating "unique" positons).

Comment: "I want to avoid looping through <Level_B>" - without an explanation as to *why*  you want to avoid that, this seems like an arbitrary restriction preventing you from taking the most-obvious approach to solving your problem. People are less likely to jump in with suggestions in a situation like this.

Comment: Of course you are absolutely right, some explanation *always* helps and 
you have a good feeling of quality and user preferences. -
In this situation I could imagine Zxcv simply wants to find out if there exists a **XPath related** approach 
in order to deepen his *XML* knowledge instead of going the most-obvious way. And a VBA/XMLDom answer could be more interesting than the felt 10,000th loop approach :-) @TimWilliams

Comment: While looping over the Level_C nodes, check each node's `ParentNode` property using something like `If not el.ParentNode Is currentParent Then: Set currentParent = el.ParentNode: i=i+1; End If`   Then `i` is the index of each "Level_B" element containing the "Level_C" node.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added my reason for asking in my original question.

Comment: If I use Debug.Print(NodePathOfValue(i).ParentNode.BaseName) I get the name of the parent node as a result. If I use Debug.Print(NodePathOfValue(i).ParentNode) I get nothing. How can I view the position number of the parent node?

Comment: I have solved this over on my blog, https://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2020/08/vba-use-domselectnodes-and-double-slash.html  The key feature you need to use is a double slash prefixed XPath expression which finds your nodes regardless of depth.

Comment: SMeaden's code probably has what you want, but you can always traverse the tree using `ParentNode`, `ChildNodes` etc to find what you want.  If you need to know the position/index of a parent node within the document then you can use the approach I outlined in my comment above.  I'm not sure why knowing the index is important though: once you have a reference to the parent you know that all related elements will be children of that node.

Comment: Thanks everybody and thanks @SMeaden for your detailed answer.